# own openvpn server, connection falls down of 5% speed

Tags: performance, openvpn, network-speed, ubuntu-22.04

I tried to set up my own openvpn server. Want to connect my devices like phone, tv, tablet, laptop and so on.

My system of the VPS:
CPU (4x):
Socket Designation: CPU 0

```
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Other
    Manufacturer: QEMU
    Version: pc-i440fx-6.2
    Voltage: Unknown
    External Clock: Unknown
    Max Speed: 2000 MHz
    Current Speed: 2000 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Other
    L1 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    L2 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 1
    Characteristics: None
```

Memory:
Physical Memory Array

```
    Location: Other
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 2 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 1
```

So I thought this would be fine for using it as openvpn server.

My speed on the vps are >600mbit/s, my home internet speed is >500 mbit/s. So, I thought I can reach 100 mbit/s... so I dont.. I just reach 2-5 mbit/s..

My configs:

server.conf:

```
    local xx.xx.xx.xx
    port xxxxx
    proto udp
    dev tun
    ca ca.crt
    cert server.crt
    key server.key
    dh dh.pem
    auth SHA512
    tls-crypt tc.key
    topology subnet
    server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
    sndbuf 393216
    rcvbuf 393216
    push "sndbuf 393216"
    push "rcvbuf 393216"
    push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
    ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
    push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
    push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
    keepalive 10 120
    cipher AES-128-CBC
    user nobody
    group nogroup
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    verb 3
    crl-verify crl.pem
    explicit-exit-notify
```

client.conf:

```
    client
    dev tun
    remote xx.xx.xx.xx xxxxx
    remote-cert-tls server
    tun-mtu 8192
    mssfix 0
    
    proto udp
    cipher AES-128-CBC
    ncp-disable
    fast-io
    
    txqueuelen 2000
    
    pull
    nobind
    reneg-sec 0
    resolv-retry infinite
    verb 3
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    remote-random
    mute-replay-warnings
    route-delay 10
```

the cpu is not realy overloaded, 10% when a client is connected.

is my system to bad, or anything else?  it is a fresh ubuntu 22.04 LTS os with no other aplications, only openvpn.

client: iphone 13 pro with 5G and WLAN testes, also tested a windows laptop.

thanks for every help.

regards,

erik

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at your configuration, seems you know the gist to make internet speed optimizations to your OpenVPN server and client.

I don't think your VPS hardware would be the downfall here.

The only thing that would come to mind is the location between you and the VPS that would suffer greatly in speed.

Another one would OpenVPN itself - Compared to Wireguard, OpenVPN does suffers great reduction in speed due to the overhead.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tested an other device which hat a speed up to 260000 kbit/s download. Now I try openVPN to an other server from my enigma2 device. Then I will see if it depends on my STB or my server. An other way will be using wireguard for my enigma 2 (STB) device.